# Unable to Create Generic Dictionary... Sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I am attempting to use a C# library in PowerShell and one of the library methods requires an argument of type `` [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]] ``.

This should be as simple as saying

```
$var = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]::new()
```

and on my Win7 development box it is... but when I deploy to my Win2012R2 server that raises the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] does not contain a method named 'new'.
```

I'm honestly not sure if this is an issue with PowerShell, C#, .NET, the Windows kernel, or maybe some combination thereof. I suspect it might even be a false positive hiding some other error (wouldn't be the first such case in this project alone).

Comment: `::new()` is a newer facility. Older versions don't support it (not sure which version introduced it off the top of my head). You should be able to upgrade the version on the server to one that supports it, since it's the same generation of Windows as your development box.

Comment: Thanks, @madreflection! When you say "the version" do you mean the version of .NET framework or something else?

Comment: It looks like it was [introduced in PowerShell 5](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/07/more-new-stuff-in-powershell-v5-a-new-way-to-construct-things/). Install PowerShell 5 on the Win2012R2 server.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Two Solutions:

### Update PowerShell

PowerShell since version 5 supports the `::new()` syntax (thanks @madreflection!)

### Change Syntax

The way to do this in PowerShell before version 5 is:

`` $var = [Activator]::CreateInstance([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]) ``